# Aurelia plugin path error

Tags: aurelia, systemjs, jspm

I installed aurelia-breadcrumbs using jspm.  config.js file has a map entry:

```
 "heruan/aurelia-breadcrumbs": "github:heruan/aurelia-breadcrumbs@0.2.6"
```

The config.js also has a path entry:

```
"github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*"
```

In my project under the directory jspm_packages/github/heruan, there are files/folders relating to aurelia-breadcrumbs.

In my boostrap config I have:

```
aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature('src/resources')
    .developmentLogging()
    .plugin("heruan/aurelia-breadcrumbs");
```

However, the plugin is not being mapped properly and it cannot find the aurelia-breadcrumbs.js file (error 404 in the browser).

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:7987/heruan/aurelia-breadcrumbs.js
```

When I look in the 'sources' tab in chrome developer tools, the breadcrumbs plugin no longer appears under jspm_packages/github.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you change the line in config.js "heruan/aurelia-breadcrumbs": "github:heruan/aurelia-breadcrumbs@0.2.6" to "aurelia-breadcrumbs": "github:heruan/aurelia-breadcrumbs@0.2.6"?

Comment: My best guess is that some config information needs to be added to the jspm registry for this plugin to teach JSPM/SystemJS what it needs to do to make this plugin work.

Comment: I thought so as well and I tried to switch the config exactly as you suggested, but then I was getting the same error with a different URL.  I just abandoned using this plugin.  I don't have the time to debug it at the moment.  It doesn't look like it's been touched in 6 months and given how often Aurelia is changing, it leads me to believe it might be abandoned.

Comment: To fix this with JSPM/SystemJS you would have to learn how "overrides" work. https://github.com/jspm/registry/wiki/Configuring-Packages-for-jspm

Comment: I am getting the same error 404. Can you please help me how did you fix it?

Comment: I am getting the same error 404. I am new to Aurelia and Javascript framework. Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: I have not idea, I gave up on this plugin.  Perhaps someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

In the /jspm_packages/github/heruan/aurelia-breadcrumbs@0.2.6/dist/commonjs/index.js file, please change this

```
function configure(frameworkConfiguration, config) {
    frameworkConfiguration.globalResources('./breadcrumbs.js');
}
```

from

```
function configure(frameworkConfiguration, config) {
    frameworkConfiguration.globalResources('/jspm_packages/github/heruan/aurelia-breadcrumbs@0.2.6/dist/commonjs/breadcrumbs.js');
}
```

this change is because,index.js file is unable to load  ./breadcrumbs.js due to some path issue or some other,instead if we provide relative path then it is loading the file

Comment: The project where I was using Aurelia has been abandoned so I cannot verify this answer.  If someone can verify, I will be happy to give credit.